# qmake adds /usr/lib absolute path when cross compiling

Tags: qt, cross-compiling, qmake

I need to cross compile a Qt app for arm. This is what I do:

```
export SDK_MXC_PATH="/path/to/sdk"
export QMAKESPEC="${SDK_MXC_PATH}/usr/mkspecs/devices/linux-imx6-g++/"
export SDK_MXC_BIN="${SDK_MXC_PATH}/toolchain/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/fsl-linaro-toolchain/bin/"
export QMAKE="${SDK_MXC_BIN}/qmake"
export PATH="${SDK_MXC_BIN}:${PATH}"

${QMAKE} -spec ${QMAKESPEC}

make
```

The mkspec file seems to be fine:

```
include(../common/linux_device_pre.conf)

EGLFS_PLATFORM_HOOKS_SOURCES = $$PWD/qeglfshooks_imx6.cpp

QMAKE_INCDIR           += $(SDK_MXC_PATH)/usr/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR           += $(SDK_MXC_PATH)/usr/lib

QMAKE_LIBS_EGL         += -lEGL -L$(SDK_MXC_PATH)/usr/lib
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2  += -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lGAL -L$(SDK_MXC_PATH)/usr/lib
QMAKE_LIBS_OPENVG      += -lOpenVG -lEGL -lGAL -L$(SDK_MXC_PATH)/usr/lib
QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL_ES2 = $(SDK_MXC_PATH)/usr/lib

QMAKE_LFLAGS           += -Wl,-rpath-link=$(SDK_MXC_PATH)/usr/lib
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE   += -DLINUX=1 -DEGL_API_FB=1 -O3 -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -fomit-frame-pointer
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE += -DLINUX=1 -DEGL_API_FB=1 -O3 -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -fomit-frame-pointer

include(../common/linux_device_post.conf)

load(qt_config)
```

Linking fails, with this error:

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -c -pipe -O2 -DLINUX=1 -DEGL_API_FB=1 -O3 -march=armv7-a -mcpu=cortex-a9 -mtune=cortex-a9 -mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -ftree-vectorize -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I../../path/to/sdk/usr/mkspecs/devices/linux-imx6-g++ -I. -I../../path/to/sdk/usr/include -I../../path/to/sdk/usr/include/QtWidgets -I../../path/to/sdk/usr/include/QtGui -I../../path/to/sdk/usr/include/QtCore -I. -I/path/to/sdk/usr/include -o main.o main.cpp
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-rpath-link=/path/to/sdk/usr/lib -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib -o qt-hello main.o   -L/path/to/sdk/usr/lib -L/path/to/sdk/usr/lib -lQt5Widgets -L/usr/lib -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lGAL -lpthread 
/usr/lib/libc_nonshared.a: could not read symbols: File format not recognized
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:183: recipe for target 'qt-hello' failed
make: *** [qt-hello] Error 1
```

I guess because it is trying to search libraries in /usr/lib

If I manually call the linker, removing `-L/usr/lib` it works and the executable can run on my target. The command below works, notice that I've removed `-L/usr/lib`

```
arm-none-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Wl,-rpath-link=/path/to/sdk/usr/lib -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib -o qt-hello main.o   -L/path/to/sdk/usr/lib -L/path/to/sdk/usr/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGLESv2 -lEGL -lGAL -lpthread
```

What can I do make `qmake` working as expected? I don't want to link manually or edit the Makefile each time it is generated by qmake.

Comment: Have you tried printing `QMAKE_LIBDIR` to check if it contains `/usr/lib` and maybe substracting it from this variable ?

Answer (score -1):

Just having the same problem w/ compiling Qt itself - seems to affect anything that calls mesa. But mesa's .pc files are okay.

OTOH, Qt creates broken .pc files. Looking at their monstrous makefile generator code, it seems they ever understood that pkg-config handles dependencies on it's own - IOW: missed the whole point. (well, they 
still didn't understand make either).

Yet the old story - still not at all suited for embedded systems.